# How to find the last non zero element in every column throughout dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can one go about finding the last occurring non zero element in every column of a dataframe?

**Input**

```
    A  B
0   0  1
1   0  2
2   9  0
3  10  0
4   0  0
5   0  0
```

**Output**

```
    A  B
0  10  2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`ndarray.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argmax.html) and advanced indexing:

```
first_max = df.values[df.ne(0).values.argmax(0), range(df.shape[1])]
out = pd.DataFrame([first_max], columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,0,10,0,0] , 'B': [0,2,0,0,0,0]})

first_max = df.values[df.ne(0).values.argmax(0), range(df.shape[1])]
# array([10,  2])
pd.DataFrame([first_max], columns=df.columns)

    A  B
0  10  2
```

---

**Update**

In order to find the *last* nonzero:

```
row_ix = df.shape[0]-df.ne(0).values[::-1].argmax(0)-1
first_max = df.values[row_ix, range(df.shape[1])]
out = pd.DataFrame([first_max], columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: sorry I messed up the input, could you direct me on how to find it for the LAST nonzero in a column?

Answer (score 14):

You can convert `0` to missing values, use forward filling and select last row by indexing, last cast to integer:

```
df = df.mask(df==0).ffill().iloc[[-1]].astype(int)
print (df)
    A  B
5  10  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
results = {}
for column in df.columns:
    results[column] = df.loc[df[column]!=0, column].iloc[-1]
```

This will make a dictionary with all columns as keys and they last non-zero values as values.

EDIT:
If you want it in a dataframe, plus dict comprehension for one-liner:

```
results = pd.DataFrame({column:[df.loc[df[column]!=0, column].iloc[-1]] for column in df.columns})
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the columns then the rows and store the last non zero variable

```
list = []* number_of_columns
for i in range(len(df)):
    dfcolumn = df[:,i]
    for item in dfcolumn:
        if item !=  0:
            list[i] = [i, item]

print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile)

**Given**

```
import itertools as it

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": [0, 0, 9, 10, 0, 0], 
     "B": [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
)
```

**Code**

```
#3                 2                 1 
[next(it.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, reversed(col))) for _, col in df.iteritems()]
```

Output

```
[10, 2]
```

---

**Details**

With each column in the DataFrame, we want to

1. iterate the column in reverse, e.g. `[0, 0, 10, 9, 0, 0]`
2. drop all zeros up to the first non-zero element, e.g `[10, 9, 0, 0]`
3. get the next element from the iterator, e.g. `10`